# python 2.7 string_name.find() function always returning -1 when using variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, find

*Python 2.7 on Windows 10*

So, I've started trying to use a function that, in all of my examples, locates the first iterance in a string of the requested word.

Example:

```
message = "Hello, World." 

print(message.find('World'))
```

and it will return:

```
7
```

This works for me. However I'm trying to give a string, then ask if the user would like to locate a word within that string. If the answer is yes, the program is asking which word and the input from the user is being assigned the variable `dokokotoba` and then I'm trying to find the word `dokokotoba`.

The program runs fine in all aspects save that every time I try to find a word, it returns -1, which indicates failure.  I don't understand why. Is it because I can't use a variable there? If so, I can't see why not.

[image]

Comment: Post your code **as text**, not as an image, please.

Comment: Use:  **if "what" in "whot wheout what wahaha":** for best performance

Comment: Martijn, I will do that from now on, thank you.

SDilmac, that's supposed to be the same function as .find?

Comment: Also, if anyone can explain to me why my question is being downvoted, I'd appreciate it. I'm brand new to this site and if I'm doing something wrong and being penalized for that, I can understand and accept that, but if I don't know _what_ I'm doing wrong, I'm bound to repeat it out of ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the *string* `'dokokotoba'`, not the value of the variable. That string is not present in `message`, no.

Pass in the *variable*, not a string literal:

```
message.find(dokokotoba)
```

Note the lack of quotes there.

Demo:

```
>>> message = 'foo bar baz'
>>> message.find('bar')
4
>>> dokokotoba = 'bar'
>>> message.find(dokokotoba)
4
>>> message.find('dokokotoba')
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `.find('dokokotoba')` instead of `.find(dokokotoba)`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is

```
message.find(dokokotoba)
```

and not

```
message.find('dokokotoba')
```

In the second case you are simply searching for the string `"dokokotoba"` in the message.